# Improve processing speed c# datagridview foreach checked row

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable loaded into my datagridview.
One functionality is to send a Mail to all selected recipients.
Before doing so I have to get the selected data first out of my raw datatable.

However, if I have a huge datatable and want to look for the checked cells, the whole process takes too long (1-3 minutes).

```
private DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        DataTable sdt = new DataTable(); //"Selected Datatable"
        int i = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; z++) // Add Columns to Datatable sdt
            sdt.Columns.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[z].HeaderText);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Row.Cells["CheckboxHeader"].Value)) // Go on if Checkbox is checked
            {
                sdt.Rows.Add();
                for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; ++j)
                {
                    sdt.Rows[i][j] = Row.Cells[j].Value;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return sdt;
    }
```

How can I access all the checked Rows at once?

Comment: Why not when the user ticks a cell you store that records ID. This way you wont need to iterate through the table.

Comment: You are using it backwards.  Rather than iterating DGV rows to create DataTable rows, bind the raw data to the DGV, then do whatever you want based on the checked/selected status.

Comment: @JeremyThompson But then I would have to handle the event in case the User misclicked the wrong row. In this case I'd have to erase that entry again.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp I don't understand that, could you give me an example?

Comment: Where do you call method `GetDataTable`? You want to identify which rows are selected in the GridView? Why not have a boolean column in the datatable which you are binding to the GridView. And use that column value to check if it is selected or not....

Comment: UI Controls make for horrible data storage.  The DGV is meant to *display* data.  So put the data in the datatable at the outset - including a bool column to handle the check/selected status -- then use it as a datasource.  It is trivial to get the all rows from a DataTable based on a criteria.

Comment: Hi, I added a bool column to my datatable and bound it to my checkboxcolumn from my datagridview. How do I process the checkbox events? 
On mouseclick up?